# Contar las filas de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Alguien sabe porque me sale 48 filas si la tabla listalive solo tiene 25?

```
  $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listalive";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("El numero de filas son %d.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: como es el diseño de tu tabla 'listalive' ?

Comment: Muestra lo que obtienes saca captura, muestra tu tabla(datos)

Comment: Select count(*) es cualquier cosa, antes no te da error. Debes usar `SELECT COUNT( nombrecampo ) AS total ...` y luego hacer fetch y leer el valor en la clave total. Ojalá que nombrecampo sea el nombre de un campo autonumérico, o una clave primaria

Comment: Lo que necesito es sacar el numero de filas que tiene la tabla 'lisalive' independientemente de los campos.

Comment: la tabla: 
$sql= "CREATE TABLE listalive(
id INT(24) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

nombre VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
status VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
)";

Comment: Luego la llene con 25 filas:
$sql = "INSERT into listalive(name, status)
  VALUES('Eva','Alive'),('Alen R.','Alive'),('Inna','Alive'),('Francisco','Alive'),('Axel','Alive'),
 ('Alejandro Acho','Alive'),('Andrea','Alive'),('Joana C','Alive'),('Jose Antonio','Alive'),('Kevin','Alive'),
  ('Sebastian','Alive'),('Alberto','Alive'),('Alejandro','Alive'),('Bruna','Alive'),('Joana B','Alive'),
   ('Mounir','Alive'),('Sergi','Alive'),('Diego','Alive'),('Elena','Alive'),('Magali','Alive'),
   ('Ümit','Alive'),('Javier','Alive'),('Alex','Alive'),('Maggie','Alive')";

Answer (score 2):

Esto es un problema de concepto, porque al hacer una consulta con solo `COUNT(*)`, mysql te va a devolver solo una fila con un resultado y, de hecho, `mysqli_num_rows()`debería devolver solo `1`, a menos que `$result` provenga de otra consulta.

La forma correcta de obtener las filas usando `COUNT(*)` es:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listalive";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Obtener resultado en array numérico
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  // Solo debe tener un elemento, porque solo hay una columna
  $rowcount = $row[0];
  printf("El numero de filas son %d.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($conn);
```