# ¿Cómo generar registros limitados?

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, mí duda es la siguiente quiero generar un sistema de permisos laborales ya tengo el insert y los validadores pero al momento de querer meter un código el cual me ejecute un count de aproximadamente el usuario ya que si son tres veces ya no me dejara meter en un mes los registros pero no me sale.

```
<?php
  $sql_connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:4473", "root", "", "usuarios");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  session_start();

  $comentario=!empty($_POST['comentario']) ? $_POST['comentario'] : NULL;
  $fecha_peticion=!empty($_POST['fecha_peticion']) ? $_POST['fecha_peticion'] : NULL;
  $nuv_labor=!empty($_POST['nuv_labor']) ? $_POST['nuv_labor'] : NULL;
  $num_reg = +1;
  $date = date('m/d/Y ', time());    

  $sq="SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'usuario' FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'";

  if (mysqli_query($sql_connection, $sq>3)) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO perm (comentarios, fecha_peticion, nuv_labor,fecha_regis ,num_reg,estatus, usuario) 
    VALUES ('$comentario', '$fecha_peticion', '$nuv_labor', NOW(),'$num_reg','Pendiente' ,'".$_SESSION['usuario']."' )";

    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>';
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($sql_connection);
  }
  /*empezaria query*/     
?>
```

Comment: gracias muy amable

Comment: Esta pregunta fue formulada en facebook y por aquí y sigo sin entender.

Comment: Pasa por aquí para ver la solución: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/337884/contar-las-filas-de-una-tabla/337949#337949